# Ffmpeg pcm to mp3 for android

Tags: android, mp3, pcm, android-ffmpeg

```
-y -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f s16le -i xxx.pcm -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128K yyy.mp3
```

I use sampling rates of 8000, PCM convert mp3 is right.

When I use sampling raets of 16000, PCM convert mp3 is wrong.

How can I fix it?

Comment: start by posting your question in the question, and not as an image. Then perhaps you will get some attention. Also visit [this link on how to ask a good question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: “-y -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f s16le -i xxx.pcm -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128K yyy.mp3”

I use sampling rates of 8000, PCM covert mp3 is right. 
When I use sampling rates of 16000, PCM covert mp3 is wrong. 
How can I fix it.
Please help me. 
How can I change the code.

Comment: You should write the text of the question into the question area. Check the link posted by @Takarii about how to ask a good question!

Answer (score 0):

"-y -ac 1 -ar 16000 -f s16le -i %s -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 %s"

Comment: thank your answer.  sorry now relay. my account  is missing.